# No ServiceType registered

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

Getting up to speed with .NET 6 and trying to get a working example using DI and a console app.  When starting up I get an error trying to get a reference to my service class.
What am I missing?

System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type 'ConsoleEfcore.StoreCtxFactory' has been registered.'

**Program.cs**

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

using ConsoleEfcore;
using ConsoleEfcore.StoreModels;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");




// get settings from config file
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false);

IConfiguration config = builder.Build();
var Option1 = config.GetSection("TestSettings:Option1");
string Opt = Option1.Value;


var SvcBuilder = new HostBuilder()
               .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
               {
                   services.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole())
                   .AddScoped<IStoreFactory, StoreCtxFactory>();
               });

var host = SvcBuilder.Build();
DoStuff(host.Services);

host.Run();



static void DoStuff(IServiceProvider services)
{
    using IServiceScope serviceScope = services.CreateScope();
    IServiceProvider provider = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;

    StoreCtxFactory store = provider.GetRequiredService<StoreCtxFactory>();

    // lets test
    StoreContext ctx = store.GetStoreContext();

    int prodCount = ctx.Products.Count();
    Console.WriteLine($"We have {prodCount} products");
}
```

**StoreCtxFactory.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ConsoleEfcore.StoreModels;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ConsoleEfcore
{
    public interface IStoreFactory
    {
        public StoreContext GetStoreContext() ;
    }

    public class StoreCtxFactory : IStoreFactory
    {
        private IConfiguration  _config;
        private readonly DbContextOptionsBuilder<StoreContext> _bldr;
        private StoreContext _ctx; 

        public StoreCtxFactory(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
            _bldr = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<StoreContext>();
            _bldr.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("StoreConn"), sqlOptions => sqlOptions.CommandTimeout(600).EnableRetryOnFailure());
            _ctx = new StoreContext();
        }

        public StoreContext GetStoreContext()
        {
            StoreContext retval = _ctx;
            return retval;
        }
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You registered with the abstraction

```
//...

.AddScoped<IStoreFactory, StoreCtxFactory>()

//...
```

but try to resolve with the implementation.

```
StoreCtxFactory store = provider.GetRequiredService<StoreCtxFactory>();
```

Refactoring to use the registered abstraction

```
//...

IStoreFactory store = provider.GetRequiredService<IStoreFactory>();

//...
```

will stop that error